# Toggle does not show data as intended when clicked

Tags: angular, if-statement, bootstrap-4, angular7, toggle

I've been trying to display a list of data from the server using a toggle.

During the first load, the data will only be displayed according to the checkbox filter (disabled 'Show All'). This one works.

[Here is how data shows after filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiK0u.png)

But somehow, when i click the toggle to show **all the data existed** in the list, it does not working. (p/s: here user cannot filter anything because it only shows all data available.)

[Supposedly, all data should be shown, but here it does not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imPjx.png)

I'm using Angular 7 and Bootstrap 4. Thanks.

**HTML** :

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch mb-4">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-all" (click)="toggleAll('showAll')" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-all">{{ showAll ? 'Show All' : 'Sho All' }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2" *ngIf="this.showAll === false">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-filter-issmeapproved" value="true"
            formControlName="isSmeApproved">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-filter-issmeapproved">Approve By SME</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2" *ngIf="this.showAll === false">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-filter-istaapproved" value="true"
            formControlName="isTAApproved">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-filter-istaapproved">Approve By TA</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2" *ngIf="this.showAll === false">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-filter-transfered" value="true"
            formControlName="isTransfered">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-filter-transfered">Transferred</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngIf="this.showAll === false">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-filter-dorreport" value="true"
            formControlName="isDorReport">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-filter-dorreport">DOR Report</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS** :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formFilter = this._formBuilder.group({
        keyword: null,
        isSmeApproved: null,
        isTAApproved: null,
        isTransfered: null,
        isDorReport: null
    });

    this.trimData();
    this.toggleAll('showAll');

}

trimData() {
    this.formFilter.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(this.formFilter.value),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            tap(() => {
                this.tableLoading$.next(true);
            }),
            debounceTime(600),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(formValue => {
                return this._dataExtractionService.getReports()
                    .pipe(
                        tap(() => {
                            this.tableLoading$.next(false);
                        }),
                        map(report => {

                            if (this.showAll === true) {

                                if (formValue.isSmeApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isSmeApproved)
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTAApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTAApproved);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTransfered) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTransfered);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isDorReport) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isDorReport);
                                }

                            } else {

                                if (formValue.isSmeApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isSmeApproved);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isSmeApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isSmeApproved);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTAApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTAApproved);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isTAApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isTAApproved);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTransfered) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTransfered);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isTransfered) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isTransfered);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isDorReport) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isDorReport);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isDorReport) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isDorReport);
                                }
                            }

                            return report;
                        })
                    )
            })
        )
        .subscribe();

}

toggleAll(type) {
    if (type === 'showAll') {
        this.showAll ? (this.showAll = false) : (this.showAll = true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already configured the error. I just need to remove the filter inside the if-statement so that it wont filtered out the data during Show All, thus showing all data.

```
trimData() {
    this.formFilter.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            startWith(this.formFilter.value),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            tap(() => {
                this.tableLoading$.next(true);
            }),
            debounceTime(600),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(formValue => {
                return this._dataExtractionService.getReports()
                    .pipe(
                        tap(() => {
                            this.tableLoading$.next(false);
                        }),
                        map(report => {

                            if (this.showAll === true) {

                                if (formValue.isSmeApproved) {

                                }

                                if (formValue.isTAApproved) {

                                }

                                if (formValue.isTransfered) {

                                }

                                if (formValue.isDorReport) {

                                }

                            } else {

                                if (formValue.isSmeApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isSmeApproved);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isSmeApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isSmeApproved);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTAApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTAApproved);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isTAApproved) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isTAApproved);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isTransfered) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isTransfered);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isTransfered) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isTransfered);
                                }

                                if (formValue.isDorReport) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => r.isDorReport);
                                }
                                if (!formValue.isDorReport) {
                                    report.extractedReport = report.extractedReport.filter(r => !r.isDorReport);
                                }
                            }

                            return report;
                        })
                    )
            })
        )
        .subscribe();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your toggle function is not getting called.

That's because you are using **bootstrap custom control** which is just a view box replacing the original input(which stays hidden). You can inspect the page and will see that input is not where the checkbox appears but in shifted position. This cause the `click` event from not firing.

Just change `click` event to `change` event.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch mb-4">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-all" (change)="toggleAll('showAll')" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-all">{{ showAll ? 'Show All' : 'Sho All' }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: i've already did as you mentioned but the result is still the same. is it because of the if-statement? but i'm not sure how.

Comment: @gosling3 Is your function getting called? Just do a console log. If working check whether the `showAll` variable is changing value as expected.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this, when i clicked 'Show All', it does not get called. i'm a bit confused where should i call it.

Comment: It's supposed to be working if you have called in change event. Can you provide a stackblitz demo with dummy data?

Comment: tried to do the demo using stackblitz but there were too many errors

Comment: @gosling3 Just give the demo. I'll try to fix the errors. Make sure data is provided.